# How to store the last TWO folders of my current directory in a variable for my .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to do an FTP using a .bat file. Now the location I'm taking from will partially match the location on the main drive. I am doing an `mget *`  from that location.

**Example:** `\...\...\Folder1\Folder2`

Now on my system, I have folder location `\....\....\Folder1\Folder2`

I want to match those for the script. Right now I'm trying to use

```
SET MYDIR=%cd%

set MYDIR1=%MYDIR:~41,7%

for %%f in (%MYDIR1%) do set myfolder=%%~nxf
echo %myfolder%
```

This gets me the last folder, (Folder2). However the folders are going to be different, I'm placing the .bat file in different folders to do the same thing so I want it to correspond to the different directories no matter the size of the folder name, so I can't use a hardcoded subscript. So then I thought maybe get name of folder2 and then delete it from the string, but I'm having trouble deleting the variable with folder2 text from the string. I can delete specific string from the text, however it won't know from one folder to the next what the string is going to be.

Suggestions? I basically want the last TWO folders as variables so I can pass them to my script that will drawl from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the child and parent directory names of the current directory using the `FOR` command.

```
for %%G in ("%cd%\.") do set child=%%~nxG
for %%G in ("%cd%\..") do set parent=%%~nxG
```